# Eclipse CDT - missing "Archives" and "Includes" in Project Explorer

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have multiple projects open under a single workspace. They were 2 separate code repos, and I imported them separately by clicking on `File` , `New`, `Makefile Project with Existing Code`.

In additional to the folders that already exist for the project itself, the first project had "Binaries", "Archives", and "Includes" folders automatically generated. When I click on, say, "Includes", I see things like "/usr/include". That makes sense to me.

These automatically generated folders did not appear for the second project. Is that sign of something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question - the problem is when you do `Makefile Project with Existing Code`, you need to specify a compiler for the indexer. My problem was that I clicked on "None" instead of something reasonable like "Linux GCC". I removed the project and added it back in with "Linux GCC", and everything is fine.